# jquery help for div having same prefix id

Tags: jquery

I have 4 DIV's with different ID's (but have same prefix (testDiv[1|2|3|4]) ) and i want to set their visblity(visible or hidden) on some event. 
How can i use to set the DIV visiblity property at one times something like

```
$('testDiv*').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
OR
$('testDiv*').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

There is workaround to this problem. I can have a class named ".comnClass" for all the DIV's and change its property 
But i want a solution having four different DIV id.

THANKS ALL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [starts with selector `^=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like this:

```
$('div[id^=testDiv]').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

> Description: Selects elements that
>   have the specified attribute with a
>   value beginning exactly with a given
>   string.

***Note*** that if you use a class instead, you can target them easily but that depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Having a common class is not the workaround. It *is* the right way to do it. The class establishes the relationship between these four elements so that you can manipulate them in a single go. The `id` is used to be able to identify them uniquely.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div[id^=testDiv]').attr('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: THANKS Daren Sarfarz
Its not attribute but css

Comment: and its not visible but 'visiblity'

Comment: @user367134, yes it's `visibility`. Updated post.